# differentiating diffusion pde under the integral sign

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I got little bit confused about how we differentiate the diffusion PDE:
-Let u(x, t) be the concentration (mass per unit length) of the dye at position x of the pipe at time t.
-In the section of pipe from x0 to x1 , the mass of dye is:
$$M(t)= \int_{x_0}^{x_1}u(x,t)dx\Longrightarrow \frac{dM}{dt}=\int_{x_0}^{x1}u_t(x,t)dx $$ and differentiating with respect to $x_1 $
We get $u_t$ could anyone help me out ? 
Thanks

Comment: You differentiate $M$ with respect to its variable $t$ which amounts to differentiating under the integral sign which in turn is legitimate since $u$ is continuously differentiable in $t$ by assumption/need. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I just didn't know if we used the fundamental theorem of calculus or Libenz integral rule because when differentiating again wrt x we have the limits of the integral as functions of x or am I wrong?

Comment: Differentiating $M$ with regard to $x$ yields zero as $M$ is a variable of $t$ only. Also, the limits of the integral are just values and can be renamed $s_0, s_1$.